# How can I launch an external python process from Excel 365 VBA on OSX?

Tags: vba, macos, excel

I have a VBA macro in Excel 365 on OSX that I want to have launch an external process (a python script) that will generate a file for importing into Excel.

I've tried a number of things, but none of them are working for me. I've listed them below.

My first attempt was to use:

```
Shell ("/usr/local/bin/python /tmp/myScript.py")
>> Run-time error '76': Path not found
```

Then I read that it preferred old Mac-style paths, so did

```
Shell ("Macintosh HD:usr:local:bin:python /tmp/myScript.py")
>> Run-time error '76': Path not found
```

This, on my system, is a symbolic link, as I'm using HomeBrew, so I resolved where the link was pointing and ran that instead:

```
Shell ("Macintosh HD:usr:local:Cellar:python:2.7.10_2:Frameworks:Python.framework:Versions:2.7:bin:python /tmp/myScript.py")
>> Run-time error '76': Path not found
```

And just in case, I tried that one with unix-style paths:

```
Shell ("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /tmp/myScript.py")
>> Run-time error '76': Path not found
```

Then I tried running it using MacScript:

```
MacScript ("do shell script " + Chr(34) + "/usr/local/bin/python /tmp/myScript.py" + Chr(34))
>> Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument
```

So it seems to me that MacScript() isn't available in this version of VBA.

Then I found an article describing how to reveal the `system` method in libc:

```
Private Declare Function system Lib "libc.dylib" (ByVal command As String) As Long
system("/usr/local/bin/python /tmp/myScript.py")
>> Compile error: The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems. Please review and update DEclare statements and then mark them with the PtrSafe attribute.
```

Doing a bit more digging to check where I should add this gave me:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function system Lib "libc.dylib" (ByVal command As String) As Long
system("/usr/local/bin/python /tmp/myScript.py")
>> Run-time error '453': File not found: libc.dylib
```

Thinking that it might be sym-link related again, I found that there was a chain of sym links `libc.dylib -> libSystem.dylib -> libSystem.B.dylib`, so the last thing I tried was:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function system Lib "libSystem.B.dylib" (ByVal command As String) As Long
system("/usr/local/bin/python /tmp/myScript.py")
>> Run-time error '453': File not found: libSystem.B.dylib
```

And that was as far as I managed to get. Can someone point me in the right direction from here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while, but I figured out how to do it.

Excel 2016 has replaced `MacScript()` with `AppleScriptTask()`. This needs to be given an AppleScript file and function to call, and can't, as far as I am aware, be given raw AppleScript commands.

I created an AppleScript file called PythonCommand.scpt which contained something like:

```
on PythonCommand(pythonScript)
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/python " & pythonScript
end PythonCommand
```

This AppleScript file needs to be then placed in `~/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel/` (create this folder if it doesn't exist)

Once this is here, the function can be called using:

```
Dim result As String
result = AppleScriptTask("PythonCommand.scpt", "PythonCommand", pythonScript)
```

(it insists on returning something - it won't work without this)

A security proviso:

- Any Excel macro can call this AppleScript. Macros can do nasty things anyway, but it would be worth putting some protection into it anyway to avoid additional code being executed.